# How to Find Certain Areas of a Variable AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I do not have a project or anything, I just wanted to know if this was possible.

Let's say I have a variable that is a string,

```
var code:String="hello there"
```

is there any way possible I could keep that variable the same, while using it for only the first 10 letters (or any number of letters)?

For example, if I had 2 dynamic textboxes, could I assign one the first four letters of the variable, and the other one the last four letters of the variable?

Also, could I recognize a charCode and make that the endpoint? For example, could I recognize when a space occurs, and do all letters before that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `substring` for extracting. Read this excellent **[article](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web2/action/ch04_06.htm)** (section **4.6.6**). The first char starts as zero index pos. -- (Untested but..) try : `mytxtBox.text = code.substring(0, 4);` then use `trace` to check that textbox only contains "hello" (if no visual feedback). -- Just something to get you started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var parts:Array = code.split(" ");
```

Will do just like it says: split the string at all occurrences of the delimiter, which in this case is space.